# Redirect TCP port traffic to other port so that the Java application knows which port was used

Tags: java, linux, tcp, proxy, bungeecord

I am running a Java server application (Bungeecord if anyone knows) for which I'm coding plugins. The Bungeecord server runs on port A but one needs to be able to connect to the server on port A and B. So if one connects to port A everything should work as expected. But if one connects to B the input of B should be sent to port A and the output of a connection over B needs to be sent from port B.

The problem is that my Java plugin for Bungeecord needs to know whether the client connected over A or B.

I can't simply create two `ServerSocket` instances (one for port A and one for port B) because this would require modding of Bungeecord (which is not my project). Doing so would be very time intensive.

Is it possible to solve this problem on linux (debian) and with Java or do I need to create my own lightweight proxy application that provides information for the Java plugin whether a specific connection is connected ofer A or B?

Comment: I didn't understand the question, I was reviewing old bungeecord questions to attempt to tag them correctly.

You probably already know, but bungee can disambiguate based on the domain connected from, as well as listen on multiple ports.

Answer (score 2):

From the TCP layer, an application is only provided information about the port it actually receives the connection on, and that would be port A in your case. You could use a tool like `netcat` as some kind of "funnel" so connections to port A and port B always end up at port A, but the TCP layer will not carry any information about that.

If you need to separate multiple connection types that are all received at the same port in the server application, you have the following options:

- Embed information about the connection type at the application layer.
- Distinguish connections by the *source* port, i.e. the port at the client side. (You might or might not be able to use `netcat`, then. You could still use packet rewriting/port address translation, though.)

Comment: Can I be sure that the incoming TCP connection is really from the port that is sent in the packet? Cause one could actually send a TCP packet that says it'd come from google.com and actually coming from my IP and port.

Comment: No, you cannot be sure that an incoming TCP connection really originates from the port the operating system tells you, even if you can verify that bidirectional communication is possible, i.e. if data you send is received at the other end. When using `netcat` or `ssh` to forward/tunnel a connection, the originating host and port will be the ones of the tunnel end point, not the one of the client application. The same is true in case of network/port address translation along the route. If these issues are important in your case, you have to embed the connection type into the connection itself.